Does the universe not being locally real mean anything for our daily lives?
So this is more to do with the "new" (relatively) discovery that won the Nobel Prize that proved that Quantum Physics is not locally real. I'm familiar with the Scientific American article, but I take issue with it in that it seems to be overly sensational in tone and in terms of implications. I've asked this question to physicists, and the answers I got were that these findings don't have the implications people are drawing from it.
How I understand the issue is that the particles are non-local, and though their findings are preliminary, they did prove non-locality, which just means particles don't have to be near each other to affect each other. I just find it odd that people are drawing conclusion like anti-realism when the research doesn't say that. Are any of the more sensational conclusions warranted because it just seems to apply to the quantum world and not our classical lives?
(This was sorta inspired by the top answer to this question: What are the ontological implications of that “the universe is not locally real” in quantum mechanics?)

I don't know who's drawing those conclusions. But I can certainly imagine people seeing "not real" and reading that as "doesn't exist", with little regard for the fact that the actual definition of "real" being used is roughly "having definitive properties". One of the biggest challenges of science communication is in getting the public to not misunderstand the results - that happens way too often for a bunch of reasons.

No, there is no way to escape non locality. The “non locality or realism” is a false dichotomy. You can't escape non-locality in the context of quantum mechanics since the phenomenon of non-local correlations exists at the quantum level regardless of which interpretation you believe in. You are also correct that there is nothing about QM that says that realism is false

The only useful truths that you can get from popular science journalism are references to potentially interesting articles in scientific journals and additional support for the indisputable fact that journalists are stupid and immoral. No exceptions. Ever.

Bell's Theorem showed that if the world operates according to local realism under the usual local causal chain conception with predetermined statistical properties of particles, then certain statistical correlations properties predicted by QM would've not be observed even adding local hidden variables. Non-locality does not imply that everything is non-local or that the universe is fundamentally non-real. It only tells us that at the quantum level, entangled particles can influence each other instantaneously, no matter the distance...

See what I mean? Here we have a smart, well-intentioned person. The kind of person who tries hard to only believe things that are true. But he made a terrible mistake! He read some science journalism and thought it was giving him information beyond references and reasons to mock the profession of journalism. And as a result, he believes nonsense.

@gs I am assuming that you think Double Knot’s statement that entangled particles can influence each other instantaneously is nonsense. However, many physicists actually do believe this and many are taking this seriously. There are also interpretations of QM (such as Bohmian mechanics) that posit just these kinds of influences. Ironically, some physicists think it to be nonsense that these influences that would explain non local correlations are not occurring.

This question should really be updated with links to the articles involved plus answers to @Lowri 's questions. As it stands it just expresses a feeling of "oddness" about -- I don't know about what. (Yes -- journalism is often no more than sensaionalism - especially also in popular science physics journalism. Regrettable, but not odd.) I'm voting to close it for these reasons.

@Lowri I put the link there. But in short I’m wondering if it means anything spooky like things popping in and out of existence or that we can’t have standards of knowledge and things like that.
I found the top answer on that thread odd because it seems to imply support for anti realism but looking over their examples I just see someone who doesn’t understand the science.

@Lowri I did, you’re the only one who doesn’t seem to get what I’m saying.

@Syed you can absolutely escape non-locality. "non-local correlations" exist even in classical mechanics - it's not the correlations we care about, it's what causes them. Many Worlds can escape non-local causation and still produce the correlations.

Yes, only "non-locality" has been "proven" so far.  Non-realism -- has been proven for the Quantum theories that 98% of physics theorists use, but Bohmian Mechanics, one alternative option, is entirely real.  It is also calculationally almost unworkable, and the tests of it against the others are going badly for BM so far: https://settheory.net/Bohm.  But science has shown that emergence works and is part of our world, so global reduction isn't valid, and one can still apply "realism" to higher level phenomena in your life.

This closure seems like one more example of bad closures.  The OP asks a legitimate question, that philosophy has sought to address -- "how should we live", and relates that to recent physics discoveries that bear on fundamental oologic and epistemic assumptions behind philosophic worldviews.  The answer's that "extrapolating physics discoveries to global worldviews may be unjustified" is entirely on topic here, and is a very useful bit of wisdom.  That emergence is the mechanism to limit global anti-locality and anti-realism may be uncomfortable for some advocates of global reduction here ...

@TKoL non local correlations in classical mechanics have a common cause so that analogy is not relevant in my opinion

@Dcleve, the real issue with Bohmian mechanics is that it reveals, time and again, that physicists are determined by hook and by crook to overturn realism for their strange political agendas. The theory as it is may well be completely defective, but it's 70 years since Bohm developed it specifically to defeat the anti-realist claims at the time. What Bohm showed was that physicists, acting politically, had already jumped to anti-realist conclusions decades earlier which were not in fact necessary, and that they had positively dismissed the idea when DeBroglie earlier suggested it too. (1/2)

If BM is falsified on some probably minor detail, the majority of people (including scientists in all other fields) will not conclude that realism must go, we will conclude that physicists have strained every sinew again to jettison realism and invalidate a theory they have left practically derelict of further development for most of a century, whilst eagerly working on their own bamboozling schemes that have to be challenged belatedly by informed amateurs - or if it is challenged by a professional physicist, he'll likely be sent to Coventry, like David Bohm (almost literally) was. (2/2)

@Steve -- Your conspiracy theory that physicists are trying to invalidly push anti-realism is -- bizarre, and contrary to history.  Physics was dragged kicking and screaming into anti-realism.  That both HV and BM fail test cases (so thoroughly for HV that it is now abandoned) is physicists doing science, not physicists trying to push an ideology.  The computational problems for BM are an additional issue -- as one must know the properties of the universe beyond our event horizon to complete those calculations -- making BM explicitly non-calculable/non-predictive.

@Dcleve, it isn't contrary to history but exactly consistent with it. Physicists have not been dragged, they have been at the forefront of these absurd innovations in the tenets of scientific enquiry. I don't know what "HV" is, and my understanding of BM is that it has no distinguishing features that can be tested, except that it explains with the real what formerly physicists had insisted could only be explained with the non-real. (1/2)

And reiterating, I'm not defending the exact theoretical form of BM, I'm saying it merely shows that physicists keep jumping to absurd conclusions and persecuting dissidents because, ultimately, they prefer those particular conclusions and yearn for them, whilst systematically ignoring or suppressing alternatives, and spreading like you do FUD about things "not going well" etc. (2/2)

@Steve  Your "wish it were so" about realism does not make science a conspiracy to refute your preferred worldview.  and your seizing upon Quine-Duhem to argue against inference to the best explanation is you rejecting science in favor of your ideology.  Science relies upon usable predictions and the ability to do testing.  That Einstein's Hidden Variables failed multiple test cases, and Bohmian mechanics is also clearly going down that path -- matters to actual scientists.  It does not matter to ideologues, which looks like the case for you.

@Dcleve, most people don't wish realism were so, it is simply axiomatic to our entire world and axiomatic to scientific enquiry - there's nothing it doesn't already touch. BM has usable predictions, they are simply not distinguishing predictions - it was not formulated to falsify existing predictive models, it was formulated to show that a real explanation of those models was perfectly possible. It showed the physicists had acted corruptly by insisting they were forced to abandon realism, which is a basic tenet within which our society expects physicists to produce explanations.

@Steve You keep dragging politics into this when that isn't what is going on here.
Also a lot of people wish realism were so, we want other people that we care about to be real and exist independently of us. IF it weren't that would cause major psychological issues for humanity, let alone our social interactions.

@Ian, I disagree, the physicists are a highly political crew. And for me, realism has nothing to do with wanting people we care about to be real. It's just I'm convinced bears shit in the woods even when we are not looking, and I'm not so egocentric to believe nature was created around me.

@Steve " It's just I'm convinced bears shit in the woods even when we are not looking, and I'm not so egocentric to believe nature was created around me." That's idealism, not anti-realism. Those aren't the same. What exactly do you even understand about the interaction of concept and percept at the level of intuition which inform your views on things like ontological relativity, nominalism, and the tenability of conceptualism? Exactly whose anti-realist philosophy are you attacking?

Have you read McDowell or Sellars or Hanson? Or do you understand why epistemology moved in a post-positivist direction?

@JD, I'm attacking the anti-realism of the physicists who participate in these sites. I don't know whether they always conform to a specific position or they make it up on the hoof, but I know I'm agin it when I hear it.

@Steve I think what you have to appreciate Steve is the attitude "I know it when I hear it" is sort of anti-philosophical, which is certainly your prerogative. But from the perspective of those of us who take the time to read Duhem, Quine, Sellars, McDowell, Lewis, Dummett (those are 5% of the books I own on the topic), you come across as argumentative, but uneducated on the topic. I'm not insulting you, but just pointing out that knowledge on what constitutes anti-realism, idealism, Platonism, etc. are a necessary condition on criticizing critics of scientific realism...

You might want to start with https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/realism-sem-challenge/ if you want any serious attention from those of us who read extensively on the philosophy of science. I occupy a middle ground on the issue, so I'm not opposed to the thrust of your arguments, but it's hard to defend your certainty if you don't understand, for instance, why nominalism has influence, or why there is a controversy over natural kinds and how biological cladistics affects such a debate. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/ Keep participating! Just keep an open mind. Good luck!

@Ian You have the core of a good question. If it reopens, I'll put my $0.02 in on how scientific theories and explanations are open to interpretation. In the philosophy of science, formal results are situated in larger, natural-language frameworks sometimes called paradigms in the spirit of Thomas Kuhn. Different schools of thoughts on these paradigms emerge, and philosophical disagreement spirals into metaphilosophical disagreement, and then Sayer's law kicks in for those whose funding depends on it. :D And well, writers have to move copy. Feel free to roll back the edits.

@JD, I'm just not being drawn into abstractly characterising my opponent's philosophical positions for them, when in many cases there may be subtle (even incoherent) variations in what they all advance, and when my belief is that they adopt these positions less on their own merits, but often quite casually because of a perceived aesthetic correspondence with their political views which I believe is the actual governing factor. You asked me a series of questions and I'm simply being clear about my thinking. (1/2)

Incidentally I'm not a realist to the degree that I'm arguing scientific knowledge is objective or free of human influence, or that the real is accessible in a way that is free from questions about how we interact with it. It is merely the axiom that there exists a real world separate from our knowledge about it, and that it has definite properties or a definite form (even if, once our knowledge is removed from the equation, nothing can be said about specifically what those properties are or what that form is). (2/2)

@Steve You seem a man of intelligence and reasonable in nature. Generally, you'll find this site is mishmosh of those who come to debate, and those who come to do Q&A. As you seem to have interest, I encourage you to continue contributing as you see fit! :D

@Syed the same would be true in many worlds. No causation travels faster than light, and the causal explanation for the correlation travels at light speed or slower too

Of course not; not in the wording of your Question, anyway. First, what could anything about the universe mean for our daily lives… unless it be that we should watch out for the neutrino storm?
Further, how can 'the universe' not be locally real?
How can 'the universe' not be 'locally' anything?
How can 'the universe' not be 'real'?

@RobbieGoodwin That's what I mean, it's not saying all that but I worry because people say it does.

Really? If that's what you mean, why not go back and Edit the Question to include that meaning?
Either way, do you see anything helpful, useful or even meaningful in 'That's what I mean, it's not saying all that but I worry because people say it does…'?
How hard would it be to re-phrase such a deep meaning?

I did. Hence the last part. My worry is the nonsense people seem to draw from this stuff when not only is it largely uncertain but even the folks who do this stuff don’t fully know what’s going on.

Mathematics and the physical sciences have always been abused to draw improper conclusions, going at least as far back as the dawn of civilization, as we seen in the numerology and astrology of Sumer. Stargazing was a useful field that allowed one to organize calendars and predict the best time to plant and harvest. People decided that if the stars can do that, why can't they tell if you are going to win a war or have a successful child? That's how astrology was born. People were extremely impressed with the way that arithmetic could predict how many urns of beer would fit in the hold of a ship, so they thought it should also be able to predict how long a man's life would be and other things.
The Greeks followed this tradition and added more. They were impressed with the discovery that harmony is produced by small whole-number ratios and built a cosmology out of it. Empedocles was impressed how so many colors could be produced by just four base colors (which oddly to modern sensibilities didn't include any cool colors like blue or green), and he invented a chemistry based on four elements, inspired by the science of painting.
Newton's theory of gravitation led to the adoption of a clockwork universe by many scholars. Darwin's discovery of natural selection led to scholars trying to fit absolutely everything into an evolutionary framework, even things like the racial makeup of man (Hitler's attempt to eliminate "less fit" races) and the social acceptance of new ideas (meme theory). Einstein's theory of relativity led to three-quarters of a century of bad philosophy claiming that his theory of how one calculates the motion of particles based on a given frame of reference proved that "everything is relative" including God, morality, and even truth itself.
All of these are nonsense, of course, and were never rationally supported by the mathematics or science that gave rise to them, but people tend to think in terms of paradigms. Evolution is a nice paradigm so they try to understand everything in terms of evolution. Newtonian mechanics is a nice paradigm so they try to understand everything in that paradigm.
This is just another example of the same nonsense, people not understanding the limits of what has been scientifically proven and adopting it as a general paradigm.

everything is relative including God and morality Which God are you speaking of? The one that prescribed stoning as a punishment for blasphemy and adultery?

@Philomath, not every mention of God is an invitation to have yet another argument.

It is if it's part of a polemic that is mostly fact free opinion and which in no way answers the question (how non-locality affects our daily lives ). You write something provocative, call people out for nonsense, you can expect a reply. Here it is

All good, no hard feelings.

If you want to say e.g. viruses don't evolve, good luck explaining they spread and why vaccines work and don't work based on an evolutionary understanding of viruses. If evolution underpins all life on Earth, as it seems to, then of course much of our understanding of life would be built on that and wouldn't make much sense without it. People trying to criticise evolution tend to fail spectacularly to produce any valid criticism or offer any better explanation for the evidence. It's also an accurate analogy for many non-biological processes. Calling it "nonsense" does little to refute that.

Evolution shows all humans (and other animals) have the same ancestors, "fitness" is relative, species are adaptable and everything alive today is fit in its own way. Hardly a good foundation for murdering a race of people. Also, really sus to phrase that ("led to scholars ... Hitler") so as to imply Hitler is a "scholar" comparable to biologists that derive models from evolution. He was a bully growing up, raised in racist Christian Nationalism. Hardly a pure soul corrupted by "evil" evolution. Much genocide before we conceived of evolution - maybe Hitler would've just found another excuse.

I'd be curious if you can produce even one reputable source that uses Einstein's theory of relativity to argue that any of "God, morality, and even truth itself" is relative. There should be a source under every rock, if it really happened for "three-quarters of a century", as you claim. Whatever arguments people present for those things being relative (of varying quality), I've never once heard anyone mention the theory of relativity. Maybe the Wikipedia page on the equivocation fallacy may be helpful.

@NotThatGuy, you must be young. It was extremely common when I was younger. But no, I'm not going to do your research for you.

Okay, I found a reference linking the theory of relativity to relativism of truth and ethics. Although "Einstein did not think that the Theory of Relativity supported relativism in ethics or epistemology because ... the physical laws expressing such relativity are constant and universal and hence in no sense relative". I guess I agree it's a "nonsense" leap from one to the other, but it seems less that people said one "proved" the other, and instead used one as inspiration for the other, but I'm basing that off of like 1 quote.

"I've asked this question to physicists and the answers I got seem to imply that it's NO, this doesn't have the implications people are drawing from it."
This is almost certainly the correct take, yes. At the macroscopic level, everything you interact with is essentially as real as it seems, even if some other kind of quantum non-realism is true.

It's a strange claim to hear that local realism has just been falsified, because I thought JS Bell had already proved in 1964 that local realism was impossible to reconcile with the evidence!
There's actually two common (and subtly distinct) ways in which the concept of "locality" is used in physics.
In relativity, "locality" is the idea that cause-and-effect must mediate through space and that influences in any one area must only come from adjacent areas of space. This is standard stuff from wave mechanics. No "action-at-a-distance", no wormholes, no instantaneous global influence.
At the turn of the 20th century, it was novel to make this a fully-general principle for the first time, because hitherto some things, like Newton's gravity, had been thought to propagate the universe instantly.
In QM, "locality" is the idea that "variables" are fully encoded in a region of space occupied by the hypothesised "particle". Basically, if you fire a bullet, it's trajectory and speed are the relevant "variables" which determine where it hits.
It's the latter, QM-style of locality which has been proven inconsistent with the evidence.
In the 1930s, it was thought QM was showing such remarkable results that it might be showing inconsistency with realism. And there have always been those with a broadly anti-science and anti-rational agenda who want to fill the gaps.
Indeed we see in hindsight that physicists were largely ignoring the possibilities, tied up with their own theoretical errors, or politically persecuting those with the answers. In 1928 DeBroglie made an ill-received suggestion that proceeded from the same kind of concept as Bohmian mechanics ultimately did in 1952, which was also ill-received.
Von Neumann was also thought in 1932 to have produced a proof which showed QM was incompatible with realism - a proof that was later falsified, although it still seemed to exert a dead-hand effect long afterwards.
Bohmian mechanics is a "non-local realist" theory which posits a guiding "pilot wave". The easiest analogy I find for this is setting a rubber duck onto the sea and letting it travel wherever the waves take it. It is "non-local" because it is the sea which determines where the duck ends up, not the duck - the trajectory and speed of the duck are not variables local to the duck, and where the duck ultimately ends up cannot be determined by any measurement of the duck itself.
I can't see why these facts have any grave implications for our everyday lives, since once physics is wrested from the hands of physicists (many of whom have strange ulterior agendas that directs their behaviour, their attentions, and determines the kind of explanations they want to find or advance), it becomes apparent that the broad concepts are fairly familiar.

That Nobel prize was long overdue. Alain Aspect's experiment was done in 1982, then there were still some theoretical loopholes, but in 1998 that was conclusively solved. Nobel prize was only awarded in 2022...

Yes. It plays an important role in enabling publishers to sucker the public into buying content in which sensational speculations are erected on a vanishingly thin foundation of scientific justification.

Yes. This is an important point to make. The propaganda agenda of journalism doesn't stop just because the topic is ostensibly science.

You mean "Scientists confirm empirical basis for century old, generally accepted linguistic preference" wouldn't sell?!

No, it won't mean that you will have randomly whales and bowls of petunias falling from the sky.
It may, however, affect future quantum cryptography:

Device-independent quantum key distribution allows two users to set up shared cryptographic key without the need to trust the quantum devices used. Doing so requires nonlocal correlations between the users.

So, there is some real use for it..

The concept of an Ansible, yes? But it requires taking one half of the entangled pair(s) physically away to the second location.

@ScottRowe Sorry, don't know about Ansible. Encryption needs a common shared key that is transmitted from A to B. If you ensure that the signal consists of entangled particles, eg polarised photons, then you can avoid interception as interception necessarily is a measurement and thus collapses the quantum state, i.e. the entanglement. The Chinese did a successful experiment in 2020 that sent entangled particles from a satellite to three cities over 1200 kilometers. According to some people this could lead to an unhackable 'quantum internet'. Anyway, I am not an expert and don't claim to be one

@ScottRowe Ask Alice and Bob, they seem to be involved... Link

Someone turned a very beautiful and evocative scifi word in to a product name, which should be illegal.

@ScottRowe  Ah, I see, no it is in fact, un-ansible. Nothing to do with faster-than-light.

You make a valid point. The discovery regarding quantum non-locality is certainly groundbreaking, but it's important to clarify the actual implications. The research doesn't definitively prove anti-realism or unreality, as some might suggest. It shows that quantum particles can influence each other without being physically close, which is different from saying reality itself is non-existent or subjective. Many physicists agree that we still lack a clear understanding of how or why this happens, and there's much more to explore. The findings mainly apply to quantum systems and don’t directly impact our classical experiences or understanding of reality.

While I've upvoted this, one comment: 'real' is a word. That word on standard accounts has a standard set of implications/connotations. Locality is one of these.  Now a mystic may use the word very differently, eg. claiming and presumably feeling I communicate with the stars; they're my friends etc. Most ppl, even sympathizers would not quite understand, or be able to put themselves in the mystic's shoes

You ask:

Does the universe not being locally real mean anything for our daily lives?

If you are wondering if quantum entanglement being true means gravity will cease, cats really will walk around dead and not dead simultaneously, and whether or bodies will start crawling out of graves, I think you can safely reject the idea that non-locality has a sudden and important impact on our daily lives. As others have pointed out, quantum computation may or may not eventually influence our lives. WP points out the challenges with applied QM:

Quantum computers are not yet practical for real work. Physically engineering high-quality qubits has proven challenging. If a physical qubit is not sufficiently isolated from its environment, it suffers from quantum decoherence, introducing noise into calculations. National governments have invested heavily in experimental research that aims to develop scalable qubits with longer coherence times and lower error rates

Since the beginning, QM has been a source of philosophical conflict with scientists like Einstein looking for ways to undermine the implications. Physicists prior to QM had a very mechanistic understanding of the universe that comes in no small part of Newtonian mechanics. General relativity also affords us a wonderful mathematical framework for making calculations. Einstein is still showing us how powerful math is with recent research validating his theory. Here's an article explaining how data from observations of double pulsars affirms Einstein's calculations. (spaceaustralia.com). QM undermines our certainty and powers of prediction in the world.
Today, there are still multiple interpretations of QM findings, and the Copenhagen interpretation from my understanding as a non-physicist is that it is the interpretation taught at the undergraduate level making it the received view. There are certain topics in QM like wave-particle duality, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, and Bell's theorem which can be unsettling to people invested in their worldviews particularly where they clash with these aspects of QM above. The SciAm article you reference notes it saying:

The journey from fringe to favor was a long one. From about 1940 until as late as 1990, studies of so-called quantum foundations were often treated as philosophy at best and crackpottery at worst. Many scientific journals refused to publish papers on the topic, and academic positions indulging such investigations were nearly impossible to come by.

For modern "skeptics", QM is a constant source of woo (rationalwiki.org). Consciousness is caused by QM. Telepathy is supported by QM. QM in this way becomes like a magical force that shaky arguments can use to take a legitimate, but arcane topic in physics as a means of support of an otherwise specious argument. This even holds in science, where some physicists have begun asking questions about whether some modern physics is pseudoscience. Sabine Hossenfelder, a German physicist has a series of videos (YT) questioning some physics research which has no empirical evidence.
What is important to understand is that science has a social dimension. Researchers in the philosophy of science like Fleck, Kuhn, Feyerabend, and Gross have explored how science is actually done, and surprise! people aren't computers and behave like people. That means science is vulnerable to human motivations like sensationalism, specious argumentation (formal and otherwise), and other excesses of rhetoric and venality. Max Planck has contributed his name to a physics constant, a first-rate research institute, and the Planck's principle:

In sociology of scientific knowledge, Planck's principle is the view that scientific change does not occur because individual scientists change their mind, but rather that successive generations of scientists have different views.

You say:

I just find it odd that people are drawing conclusion like anti-realism when the research doesn't say that.

You shouldn't find it odd. Modern psychological research in the spirit of Kahneman and Tversky show that human beings are very susceptible to cognitive bias. Research by Dunning and Kruger show human beings struggle with self-insight. And the power of emotions and the limbic system to, as Goleman calls it, engage in "limbic hijacking" means that human beings, for all their capacity to do logic still struggle mightily with irrationality which is itself a topic of much philosophical contention.
If there's any doubt in your mind that intellectuals are somehow above irrationality themselves just because they are scientists or medical doctors, I encourage you to read up on the life Ignaz Semmelweiss. He entered into a conflict with the medical establishment by insisting that after working with corpses, doctors could reduce infant death by washing their hands. Given miasma theory was dominant at the time, he was ignored, ridiculed, and eventually betrayed by his wife and thrown into an asylum. It just goes to show that MDs and PhDs are just as susceptible to the disease of stupidity as the rest of us.

That's more or less what I'm getting, that any time something like "reality isn't real" or that anti-realism thread I posted say they're supported by QM I've learned to just roll my eyes at it. That's not what the science means but that won't stop people from making that their case.
Though as for the Copenhagen interpretation, I don't think that is the received view it's just the most well known one. Some say Many Worlds is supported by the information but TBH who knows for sure. Researching this stuff is tough.

MWI is woo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics?wprov=sfla1

@J D It's really not. There is some data that does support many worlds currently, but again we don't have anything definitive. But many worlds is not woo, you're thinking Multiverse. Also doesn't copenhagen say that nothing exists unless it's observed as in consciousness? Sounds pretty Wooey. Again just because it's taught in undergrad doesn't mean it's accepted, just well known.

"The many-worlds interpretation implies that there are many parallel, non-interacting worlds. It is one of a number of multiverse hypotheses in physics and philosophy." It's a type multiverse theory. But I have little interest in philosophy of physics,  so all I can say is I affirm one empirically accessible spatial-temporal extension describeable by causality. As for CI, I subscribe to embodied cognition and have some toes on antirealist currents.

@J D People who equate many worlds with a multiverse don’t understand the interpretation. I’m not sure what embodied cognition means but I do know you can’t be an anti realist and in the same vein use science for your views. Also reading back I see you’re the one who wrote that nonsense answer on the ontological implications of this while butchering science to prove your point.

@ian Whoa. Yeah, okay. So, let's set aside your claims a second. You're very confident in your answers, but I have at least 50 books on the philosophy of science, and worked my way through quite a few of them; I have a particular interest in the failure of logical positivism in particular.So let me ask you to answer a few question for you to gauge your own views? Do you understand Duhem's theme? Do you understand the nature of operationalization as Bridgman describes it? Do you understand Quine's attack on the "Two Dogmas"? Do you understand why natural kinds are controversial? ...

If you don't, you haven't really entered the world of philosophy of science yet. There are authors with lots of contrasting views on science: Gross, Feyerabend, Popper, Carnap, Quine, Sellars, McDowell, ad nauseum. Have you read any of their work? I'm not trying to insult you, but the demarcation problem is a very complex issue. And I am absolutely a defender of naturalized epistemology and the scientific methodlogies. I actually promote a weak version of scientism, for instance, insofar as I recognize like Rorty that representationalism is overstated (which would seem ironic to some).

Feyerabend isn’t really worth taking seriously on the matter and your first point kinda shows mine about the use of this stuff. If your first instinct is to throw books at me it makes me doubt you understand things. I wouldn’t say logical positivism failed and your misunderstanding of the evidence you cite doesn’t really do your point credit. Like…speak English dude, no one else on here talks like that. 50 books in and you can’t write an answer people understand. All I really know is anti realism is at odds with science and that so far I don’t have reason to doubt science aside from QM,

@Ian I say logical positivism failed because the prominent LP's admitted it failed. If the L&EP's admitted the program failed (in the 60's, btw), why would  you, a nobody with little knowledge of it, claim otherwise? We live in a post-positivist world in philosophy of science. See Zamito's https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/N/bo3634623.html

@Ian "Certainly by 1960 a great many philosophers, including many who had earlier clearly been part of the movement, were identifying themselves in opposition to what they took to be logical empiricism. And some members simply changed their minds or pursued different projects. Logical empiricism probably never commanded the assent of the majority of philosophers in either Europe or America, and by 1970 the movement was pretty clearly over—though with lasting influence whether recognized or not." https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-empiricism/

@ian These are basic facts about the history of the movement. It started in the 30's and by the time of Kuhn, Latour, Hanson, Sellars, Quine and others, it ended for a variety of reason including the failure of observation sentences, underdetermination, theory ladenness, the death of the analytic-synthetic divide, etc. If you're walking around not realizing that LP/LE ended as a failure 65 years ago, I'm not quite sure what you're doing with your time. But if you doubt me, simply ask on this forum about it. I can't read the books for you. Start with googling "why did logical positivism fail?"

I don't mean to insult you, but I think you overestimate your knowledge, and underestimate the value of reading philosophy of science books.

I think you’re over valuing the use of philosophy of science books. Because it seems like it just gets in the way of doing it. If not know that it failed hasn’t changed the outcome or course of my life that’s generally a good indication of the use or worth of any of this stuff. What I know is that we perform tests and try to explain the world and things to better predict and manipulate it. To various degrees of success. You seem to lean too much on philosophy to shore up on your misunderstanding of the science. Namely QM.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The intersection with theoretical physics and our daily lives is vanishingly small. It simply doesn't concern most people. It's why political philosophy or the social sciences can safely ignore physical ontology and whether or not the universe is locally real or not.

That’s my thought. Like…none of this really affects our daily lives.

Heck, atomic physics normally is invisible in our daily lives; we just deal with chemistry, materials science, and other abstractions closer to our own scale.

Seeing how I am now reading this answer from a handheld device relying on physics knowledge from the entire range from macroscopic to atomic, this seems like a rather superficial statement. Just because most people aren’t personally concerned with it doesn’t mean it has no meaning on our lives.

This came out after my writing the below answer:
Quantum Teleportation, one fanciful consequence of non-locality, seems to have moved a step from sci-fi to everyday reality.

Original answer
While your question focuses on non-locality in daily life, it's better to take it in the broader framing of non-locality, causality/non-determinism, duality, superposition, entanglement etc. etc.: In short QM in daily life.
Woo-ology Crash Course
There is a large cottage industry of folks connecting QM ideas (more correctly terms) to mystic/healing/wellness ideas.
In my college days in the 70s and 80s some of my friends and teachers were quite enamored of these: [Ive not read these but I think they set the direction for what follows]

Fritjof Capra — Author of Tao of Physics
Gary Zukav — Author of The Dancing Wu Li Masters and The Seat of the Soul.
Erich von Daniken who 'proved' that God was an extra-terrestrial

This was before Deepak Chopra and a host of like woo-sters:
It must be noted that many of these were highly respected scientists before becoming woo-sters

David Bohm — Creator of Bohmian QM, author of Wholeness and Implicate Order
Amit Goswami — A theoretical quantum physicist and author of books like The Self-Aware Universe and Quantum Mechanics: An Overview. Link between QM consciousness and spirituality
F. David Peat — author of Synchronicity: The Bridge Between Mind and Matter and The Black Hole: Gravity and the Nature of Time
Rupert Sheldrake — Morphic resonance, which blends consciousness with a more expansive view of nature, it touches on areas where science and mysticism meet.
Fred Alan Wolf — A physicist and author of The Quantum Leap and The Yoga of Time Travel.
Michael Talbot — Author of The Holographic Universe, Reality as a hologram

Why do I mention these?
A recurring thread in all these is the link between QM ideas, consciousness and spirituality.
In more detail:
QM-Spirituality (putative) links
1. Water Memory and Quantum Entanglement
Claim: Water has "memory," retaining the energetic imprint of substances even when diluted to the point where no molecules remain.
QM Connection: The quantum entanglement of water molecules supposedly records information about substances.
Real World Connection: This is often cited in explanations of homeopathy, suggesting water can "remember" healing properties and transfer them to the body.
Often cited in discussions of homeopathy. A popular reference is the work of Jacques Benveniste, who claimed water retains the "memory" of substances.  For more, Homeopathy and Water Memory.
2. Quantum Fluctuations and Homeopathy
Claim: Homeopathic remedies, despite extreme dilution, work because quantum fluctuations amplify the healing "essence" of the original substance.
QM Connection: Zero-point energy or vacuum fluctuations are claimed to sustain the essence of the original molecule.
Real World Connection: This bridges homeopathy with quantum field theories in very general terms.
Claims connecting quantum fluctuations to homeopathy: Quantum Healing in Homeopathy.
3. Observer Effect and Healing Intentions
Claim: Your thoughts and intentions can directly influence physical systems, like healing a person or altering the structure of water molecules.
QM Connection: The observer effect — where measurement collapses a quantum state — is invoked to argue that human consciousness shapes reality.
Real World Connection: Experiments like Masaru Emoto's "structured water" studies claim that kind or cruel words change water crystals’ shapes.
Masaru Emoto's work on water crystals and the effect of intentions or words on their structure is central to this claim.
4. Nonlocality and Psychic Connections
Claim: Psychic phenomena like telepathy or remote healing are explained by quantum nonlocality, where particles influence each other instantaneously across distances.
QM Connection: Human minds are likened to entangled particles capable of instantaneous communication.
Real World Connection: Cited as proof of the "interconnectedness of all things."
Prominent figures like  Dean Radin author of  Entangled Minds  have written extensively on psychic phenomena and nonlocality.
5. Quantum Coherence and Alternative Medicine
Claim: Alternative therapies like acupuncture or energy healing create "quantum coherence" in the body's energy field, restoring health.
QM Connection: Coherent quantum systems (like Bose-Einstein condensates) are used as metaphors for balance in bodily energy fields.
Real World Connection: Suggests the body operates like a quantum computer, and illness arises from "decoherence."
Claims of "quantum coherence" in energy healing are frequently promoted by alternative medicine practitioners.
Example: Quantum Touch: Healing Through Energy.
6. Superposition and Multidimensional Healing
Claim: Illness exists in a superposition of states, and healing aligns you with the healthiest quantum possibility.
QM Connection: The wave function represents all possible health outcomes, and intention "collapses" this into the desired state.
Real World Connection: Implies you can heal yourself by aligning with the "highest frequency" in the multiverse.
This idea appears in metaphysical and New Age healing literature. Look at popular books or websites like Gaia.
7. Quantum Fields and Vibrational Medicine
Claim: Every organ or cell vibrates at a unique quantum frequency, and diseases disrupt this harmony. Healing involves re-tuning these vibrations.
QM Connection: Quantum field theory (QFT) is taken as a mystical force underlying life and health.
Real World Connection: Devices like "frequency generators" are marketed to restore vibrational balance.
Devices marketed to "retune vibrations" often cite quantum field theories. For example, the Rife machine claims to use frequencies for healing. See Rife Therapy.
8. Time Reversal and Emotional Trauma Healing
Claim: Emotional trauma creates quantum "time loops" in your energy field. Healing techniques can reverse these loops to prevent future illness.
QM Connection : From time symmetry in quantum equations.
Real World Connection: Used in practices like past-life regression and emotional clearing therapies.
Concepts like reversing emotional trauma loops are found in past-life regression therapy and similar practices. Example: Past Life Regression Healing.
So... is this ALL true?
Many people — of many persuasions — will jump and ask: Is this all true?
So first a basic point of logic: some of those cited above may be wrong (some may be ill-intentioned charlatans) and some may be true.
The »all« is unjustified.
On the other hand there is ample evidence that some of these things work. Here is the well-known atheist Matt Dillahunty admitting that in some life-threatening situations prayer is confirmed to work and then trying very hard to explain it away.
I find it all very amusing...
So either prayer works because there's an old guy-in-the-sky who's pleased  with the genuflections.
Or its pure placebo effect.
Are there no alternatives like the creation of a positive mindset?
Here is an excerpt from a conversation between the prominent rationalist-atheist Matt Dillahunty and the Christian Glenn Scrivener.

Scrivener: ...the thing that makes you intrinsically religious (as against social questions) is that this is the most important thing in your life or helps me frame
the rest of my decisions.
Dillahunty: I wouldn't even dispute that...
The sorts of things that you're describing as religiosity are important to humans and may in fact be beneficial my objection is to whether or not there's actually a truth behind that — well God thing.
I used to irritate some atheists because I would say I can prove to you that prayer works and I can demonstrate it right now:

If you're in a cave-in and you pray you are more likely to be rescued, not because there's some God listening to answer that but because prayer has a calming effect on you which extends the amount of time that you can be trapped which extends the likelihood that you can be rescued. The question then becomes if you know that it's the calming that extends the amount of time could you do the same thing with meditation.


I would like to hope that on a philosophy forum at least we not be hamstrung by scientism-ist preconceptions.

Steven Work's additions
Context at meta 
The example of prayer ties together the mentioned statement that 'prayer sometimes works in life threating situations
Also, if ego may shift between many-worlds that are 'close', how far is that from defining consciousness as overlapping? Also psychic connections are implied, and perhaps some worlds more at faster rates so a level of future-sense may be suggested. And since much of your answer above suggests Quantum Theory, hence I thought to make these suggestions.

Welcome @stevenwork.I've allowed your edit. They sound ok. But I'm not sure I fully understand your intention. Could you pls elaborate a bit, in particular "The prayer's subjects'???

@StevenWork Thx your detailed explanation as edit. As u acknowledge, it's not suitable (as is) as part of this answer. I'll take a few hours to bi or trifurcate it into here, chat and meta as appropriate. And merry Christmas!

And others — mods formally appointed, elected  or defacto modders — pls give me few hours to move this into it's proper place. I think the special casing is appropriate given Steven's points + lack of privilege

@StevenWork Trifurcated into meta. And chat. Hope you can participate at least in chat

The question was on a specific quantum observation, and the answer is "prayers work". I think I missed a step with the link in this answer. Unless there is no coherence to be found. Maybe you pray to a quantum deity?

@tkruse decoherence — like non locality — is one of the many blessings of quantum physics.  Welcome to the party! Note the conspective answer is not Prayers work as you mock but the list in para1

So "prayers work" is just junk added on top of junk? How about adding tomorrows weather report to your answer as well, it's not less related.

"prayer sometimes works" ... and prayer often doesn't work. About as often as random chance, in fact. I brushed my teeth this morning and I narrowly avoided a car accident this afternoon. Might've been random chance, but I'll just choose to believe brushing my teeth worked to appease the tooth fairy, so they protected me. We know a lot about attributing causation, and prayer fails whenever we try to test that. The only way one can get to "prayer works" is if you just ignore all that, and you just assume that it works.

"prayers sometimes works in life-threatening situations" - I really doubt you have enough data to show that praying or not praying in those situations changes the outcome.

@keshlam I am surprised that you're conflating what I am writing with what I am ascribing to the prominent atheist-rationalist Matt Dillahunty. So Ive made the quote (last section) more explicit.

Above comment @NotThatGuy (and all other folks exercised over the phrase "prayer works")

@Rushi: Correction then: I doubt that anyone can actually demonstrate that prayer works. There is an extremely strong confirmation bias inherent in the question, in that the cases where it seems to work will be remembered more than the cases where it didn't.  Add to that placebo effect, though I am willing to grant that if there is a measurable placebo effect, that may be considered "working". But frankly, I do not think valid data exists to either support or refute the assertion, especially if, as with parapsychology, one conveniently says that it will not work in laboratory settings.

Being "prominent", or on the side that would normally be arguing against a proposal, does not prevent being completely wrong.

I was pointing out prayer has NOT been shown to directly affect anything outside of one's own mind. I do agree with Dillahunty: prayer could "work" to the same extent meditation or taking a warm bath does. It makes your brain release happy chemicals, but that in no way means any all-powerful being outside of space and time is listening to your prayer (and then zapping your brain with happy chemicals, I guess). He and I agree we have no reason to think the latter happens, and humanity will be better off replacing prayer with things with the same benefits without the huge religious baggage.

@NotThatGuy »inside vs outside mind« the big attraction of QM is that this distinction becomes disputable. »Agree with D: prayers could "work" « From the rigorous empirical outlook that QM espouses, there's no difference between "work" and work. »All powerful being« There you go — Christian classicist  Why is the all powerful monotheistic beneficent etc etc viz. Christian God relevant to this answer or question? It's necessary to note: Obviously Matt D and I don't share outlook. I'm using him to broaden the possibility between only 2 extremities: Christian God vs (Christian) atheist

@Rushi People severely overstate QM's applicability to problems with various forms of supernatural claims... "Why is the all powerful monotheistic beneficent etc etc viz. Christian God relevant" - well, technically you quoted Dillahunty in his conversation with a Christian (TWO Christians, in fact)... But it is indeed the case that prayer "working" to cause a brain state in your brain, does also NOT in any way mean there is any other type of invisible beings (or equivalent) that are listening and reacting (or equivalent) to one's prayers. But that phrasing is much more clunky and pedantic.

Sure.  There's  a major implication that non-locality implies:  the existence of GOD.  If you apply Occam's razor to physics, I believe that the existence of another dimension of agency and order beyond our own (i.e. "GOD" or at least the existence of the transcendental) is implied.

Not even close there dude. Non locality doesn’t mean other dimensions and nothing suggests god. God has to be proven to exist first.

@Ian You're assuming God = Christian God. Thats possible but not necessary. In math there are many foundational existence n uniqueness proofs For example:  An infinite cycle group with exactly one generator will be isomorphic to the integers In like manner a very non bible non Christian God can be deduced See Anselm. Or Nietzsche

@Rushi no I’m not assuming Christian god, I’m saying god period. There is nothing in physics to suggest it and to believe so speaks more to human wish fulfillment than anything else. Math doesn’t prove god either.

@Rushi Anselm just defines God to exist, with no mention of locality. That has little to do with "non-locality implies: the existence of GOD", as this answer claims. I can certainly imagine redefining "God" to refer to any form of non-locality in a sort of pantheistic sense, much like I can call this cup God. I see this cup, therefore "God" exists. But that's so far removed from any conception of God within most religions, and it implies nothing about morality or the afterlife, like most religions do. It achieves little more than confusing the issue and adding unwarranted support to religions.

"the existence of another dimension of agency" - so... in a lab, we may see subatomic particles with localised behaviour as a result of potentially non-localised causes. And you think the simplest explanation is a being in another dimension intentionally choosing to move those particles around in exceedingly consistent and predictable ways, always / whenever we look at it? So... are they trying to send us a message... which just so happens to look indistinguishable from arbitrary mindless forces? Or are they nudging reality to cause these extremely consistent effects? Make it make sense.

@NotThatGuy I agree. "non-locality implies the existence of God" is a bit strong even for me. What I would say is more like: "Non-locality (in the science domain) makes it possible to be more open to possibilities of non immediate/palpable/manifest interactions. Voilà! Prayer becomes a tolerable ontic in a not completely disjoint majesteria" Thats such a mouthful that the original should be acceptable!

@Rushi If science has demonstrated non-locality, you're kind of arguing against yourself to try to use that to say religion may exist as a separate thing. If you try to say religion is non-local, it would mean religion is within the scope of what science can demonstrate or validate, and the complete and utter failure to scientifically validate any religious claims means we aren't justified in accepting those claims. At most, I might grant that there could conceivably be some non-local effects we aren't justified in accepting yet. But, key point: we aren't justified in accepting those yet.

@NotThatGuy To most of the above I can only say "True — that..." I am a STEM teacher. We do distinguish the science-mode from the engineering-mode but we dont make a conflict about it. If, inspired by Stephen Jay Gould, we likewise allow religion (spirituality etc) and science to coexist that would be swell

@Rushi Engineering exists on top of the foundation of science, comes after it, and/or uses similar methods. It builds things based on scientific discoveries. It uses robust and reliable formulas and models, and it tests those things (keeping what works, and discarding or fixing what doesn't, arguably with the scientific method), much like science does. That's why we trust engineering. I'm not saying religion definitively can't coexist with science, but I am saying religion lacks the reliable means that science has, which leaves it with no good reason to believe any of it, as far as I can see.

@NotThatGuy Weve talked on this before... But anyway here goes.
The central point of religion is not cognitive (intellectual)
But affective-emotional; and volitional — directing our physical life. See
eg. I think its just foolish to assume that when a holy book says — God made the world in 6 days; on the first of which he made the sun, moon... — 'day' means what we normally mean. Heck in many cultures, the word for sun is day-maker, day-creator, day-Lord etc. You dont need Galileo and Newton to rebut Genesis as fact.

So to say Genesis is non-(empirical)-truth is as nonsequitur as saying: Your math thesis is wrong because your font is Helvetica.
Then what is the  point of Genesis and such texts? Im hardly religion expert but here are some possibilities (1) warning about internecine fratricidal strife (CainAbel) (2) Order common life into work and rest — weekday, weekend (3) Most crucially the two-edged sword of knowledge — once you know something its impossible to un-know. Do we need to strive to know everything? How/when/where to stop...
Strangely this lust for knowledge gains piquancy in the AI age...

@Rushi The issue with that is that it blurs the line of what's true, and it makes it harder to argue against the people who see religion as literal truth and who use religion as justification to murder other people. If someone reads Spiderman and decides the idea of protecting others is something to strive for, I have no issue with that. But there aren't billions of people worshipping a literal Spiderman, and thinking Spiderman mass-murdered people and told people to commit genocides (and that was good), and thinking Spiderman talks to people via vague feelings and voices in their head.

@Rushi If you think religion is not literally true, and any value is instead limited to emotion and inspiration, then you shouldn't be arguing against me, who holds the same position (but I think the emotional benefit is severely overshadowed by the immense baggage of poor epistemology and unjustified truth claims that is so strongly ingrained in so much of religion). You should instead be arguing against those who do think it's literally true.

@NotThatGuy Child A likes Lego, B likes (toy) guns. Nobody argues the guns are or can be real. Are they equivalent for child growth? Teenager C immerses in Harry Potter, D in porn. Equivalent? Even if the porn is strictly machine generated and non exploitative? Adult E is immersed in stories of the Ramayana, F in current wars. Irrespective of factuality, who will be more harmonious? In short fictions have nonfictional value. Just to be clear: I think literalist religion is a problem and a danger. I guess the extent of the danger varies widely across cultures

@Rushi I don't quite get your point. Reading and enjoying wizard fiction is fine (Harry Potter - maybe not, given the author and questionable themes/stereotypes). It is fine, as long as we're clear that magic is not, in any sense, real. We could argue about the appropriate ages when we should be how clear that it isn't real. But certainly almost all adults should be on the same page about that. Argue for religion as valuable "fiction", and I may just take issue with the judgement of it being "valuable" (e.g. Christianity has far too much baggage and the main characters do far too much murder).

@NotThatGuy   TBF I don't strongly distinguish HP and the Gospels. I guess Christian rednecks will get redder hearing that. AFAIC every child is a magical being. A few remember that into adulthood. A few of those few can express that remembrance eloquently. HP is one such. Wordsworth and Blake Richard Bach are others. All these make the world better by softening, dissolving the jail of normal empirical experience

@Rushi I fully support people embracing and immersing themselves in magical worlds, dressing up and role-playing. ... as long as their is a firm separation between truth and fiction. I don't want some kid falling to their death after "casting a levitation spell" and stepping off the side of a building. And I don't want some adult (or their child) dying to a preventable disease because they cast a spell they call a "prayer" to cure it, instead of seeing a doctor. And I don't want people listening to voices in their head that they call "God".

@Rushi A robust empirical epistemology is the key to successfully navigating the world. It is the most reliable way to make sure the outcomes of one's actions match one's intent. It should be the foundation of everything, but it still allows a lot of freedom for building whatever meaning that one finds appealing, on top of that. Epistemology would be a bad place to try to find meaning - that would just make you less effective at realising your intent.
